# What is the contrapositive of the this statement " If $X$ is connected and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous surjective map then Y is connected"

Tags: general-topology, logic

What is the contrapositive of the this statement " If $X$ is connected and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous surjective map then Y is connected"

I know this is an important result but what is the contrapositive of this sentence.

My efforts:

$A\implies B$

Contrapositive:   $\text{not}\;B\implies \text{not}\;A$

If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous function and $Y$ is disconnected then $X$ is disconnected.

May be I am correct but I don't know why I am not confident about the answer. I just solved it using my intuition. How to be sure about these kind of questions.

Comment: I don't how to be sure, but your answer is correct indeed.

Comment: For $A \to B$ the *contrapositive* (as you said) is $\lnot B \to \lnot A$. In the statement above we have $A=$ "$X$  is connected and $f : X→Y$ is a continuous surjective map" and $B=$ "$Y$ is connected". Thus the contrapositive must be : "if $Y$ is **not** connected, then ..."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  but why "not A" is not equal to "$X$ is not connected and $f$ is not continuous".  How to deal with "and" in negation of sentence.

Comment: "**Not** ($A$ **and** $B$)" is equivalent to "**Not** $A$ **or** **not** $B$". See [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Informal_proof).

Comment: Thus, the *contrapositve* will be : "If $Y$ is disconnected, then **either** $X$ is disconnected **or** $f : X → Y$ is **not** a continuous function".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you. your above comments have cleared my doubt. It was a basic error from my side. It's off topic: Would you advice me as a mathematician to trust upon the intuition sometimes?

Comment: @Tensor_Product - you are welcome :-) Intuition is fundamental in math ! You cannot "discover" new theorems/results with logic alone: you need intuition. But sometimes intuition makes errors. But also De Morgan is based on intuition: "it is false that a number is *even* and *odd*". It is equivalent to what ? "It is true that a number is not-even (i.e. odd) **and** not-odd (i.e. even)" or to : "It is true that a number is **either** odd **or** even" ?

Answer (score 3):

You really have a statement $(A\wedge B) \implies C$, where $A$ is "$X$ is connected", $B$ is "$f\colon X \to Y$ is a continuous surjective map", and $C$ is "Y is connected".
Applying the contrapositive to this gives $$ \neg C \implies \neg(A\wedge B),$$ which is equivalent (you can check using truth tables) to $$ \neg C \implies (\neg A\vee \neg B).$$
Hence you get the statement "If $Y$ is not connected then $f\colon X \to Y$ is not a continuous surjective map or $X$ is not connected."

Note that "or" can be a little misleading. Both $\neg A$ and $\neg B$ can hold, but it is sufficient for only one to hold.

Comment: The equivalence $\lnot C \implies (\lnot A \lor \lnot B) \,\,\equiv\,\, A\implies \bigg(\lnot C \implies \lnot B \bigg)$ probably is also helpful

Comment: "... then $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is either not a continuous or not a surjective map ..."  Failure of only surjectivity is realizable...  Let $Y$ be a 2-point set under the discrete topology and $f$ map connected $X$ to one point...

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if wrong:

You have statement

1) $A:$ $X$ is connected and $f:X \rightarrow Y$

is a continuous (and) surjective map.

2) $B$: $Y$ is connected.

Given :$A \Rightarrow B$.

Contrapositive:

Not $B \Rightarrow$ not $A$.

Not $B$: $Y$ is not connected.

Not $A:$ $X$ is not connected

or $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is not continuos

or $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is not surjective.